# How to convert POST curl to Angular http POST with gsutil of google cloud storage?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using GCP and GCS.
Now, I try to send a POST request, but in the below curl, I couldn't find a data which I have to send some data.
In this situation, how can I make a POST request using angular http?

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer [OAUTH2_TOKEN]" \
    -H "Content-Length: 0" \
    "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o/[OLD_OBJECT_NAME]/rewriteTo/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o/[NEW_OBJECT_NAME]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the cURL command provided, I'm assuming this is to [rename an existing object in a Cloud Storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects). There are many solutions and alternatives to making HTTP requests in JavaScript and a few of those solutions are by either using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or the native [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

For example, this request can be done using axios like such:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 
       Authorization: 'Bearer [OAUTH2_TOKEN]', 
       Content-Length: 0
  },
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o/[OLD_OBJECT_NAME]/rewriteTo/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o/[NEW_OBJECT_NAME]'
}

axios(options);
```

Comment: This answer is exactly what I wanted.
Thank you!